# Create a inventory movement journal in Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

This problem is driving me nuts... I don't know how to fix it.  I'm trying to create an inventory movement journal entry using the ProfitLossJournalService.

The code below runs, but it shows the transaction in the "inventory adjustment" journal.  I want it in the inventory movement jounal.

```
public void UpdateInventoryForConsumableItem(InventoryUpdate update)
{
var svc = new ProfitLossJournalServiceClient();
var cc = new CallContext {Company = "SS"};
var journal = new AxdProfitLossJournal();


var table = new AxdEntity_InventJournalTable
{
InventDimFixedSpecified = false,
InventSiteId = "MC",
InventLocationId = "MAIN WH",
JournalType = AxdEnum_InventJournalType.Movement,
JournalNameId = "InvMovJour",
Description = Constants.InventoryMovementJournalDescription,

NumOfLines = 1,
NumOfLinesSpecified = true,
JournalTypeSpecified = true,
JournalId = "InvMovJour",
JournalIdOrignal = "InvMovJour",
action = AxdEnum_AxdEntityAction.update
};


var inventoryDims = new AxdEntity_InventDim
{
InventLocationId = "MAIN WH",
InventDimId = update.InventoryDimId,
InventColorId = update.Color,
InventSiteId = "MC",
InventSizeId = update.Size,
InventStyleId = update.Style,
action = AxdEnum_AxdEntityAction.create
};


var entry = new AxdEntity_InventJournalTrans
{
InventDimId = update.InventoryDimId,
TransDate = DateTime.Now,
ItemId = update.ItemId,
CostMarkupSpecified = false,
InventRefTypeSpecified = false,
LineNumSpecified = false,
JournalType = AxdEnum_InventJournalType.Movement,
JournalTypeSpecified = true,
Qty = update.Quantity,
QtySpecified = true,
InventDim = new AxdEntity_InventDim[1] {inventoryDims}
};



table.InventJournalTrans = new[] {entry};

journal.InventJournalTable = new[] {table};


try
{
var result = svc.create(cc, journal);

Logger.LogTrace(string.Format("sending InventoryTransferJournal {0}", result.GetValue(0)));
Logger.LogEvent(Logger.SentConsumableInventoryUpdateToDynamics);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Logger.LogException(e);

throw;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you  use the `ProfitLossJournalService` that is essentially what you are creating, an Inventory adjustment.

If you want to create an inventory movement journal, unfortunately there is no standard AIF service that does that. You would need to implement that yourself and expose it to AIF.